# Cortana Skill - Take screenshot of client desktop

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I built a Cortana Skill using MS Bot Framework V4 (Node.js) and deployed in Azure. I am able to invoke the skill using Cortana within a Windows enabled laptop.

I want to trigger Cortana to take screenshot of the client desktop where Cortana is running and save it.

Unfortunately, Cortana does not have a built-in functionality to take screenshot so I am wondering how would this be possible.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you, snip and sketch UWP supports this with deep linking and an obscure protocol handler.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-screen-snipping

```
     var theURI = encodeURI("ms-screenclip:source=\"cortana\"");
     var msg = new builder.Message(session)
       .text("Taking a screenshot ")
       .speak("Taking a screenshot ")
       .sourceEvent(
           {
               cortana: {
                   action: {
                       type: "LaunchUri",
                       uri: theURI
                  }
               }
           });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I finally created a batch file which can be triggered from Cortana.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like "Snipping Tool" don't work.  However if you see "prtScrn" on your keyboard and click that.  A bmp of your desktop will be copied to clipboard, where you can then open "paint" and "paste".

If you don't have a prtScrn button, hit the WIndows key and type "on-screen keyboard".  You will see a prtscn button there you can use.

If this is a surface, use FN+spacebar.

Or, you can always download snaggit and use it or its delayed screenshot feature.

Comment: Or use OBS or do a Teams conference with a video desktop capture and then grab a frame... 100 ways to skin this problem.

Comment: Actually, I want to trigger it from Cortana :)